# extract number of online peers for zabbix

Tags: sed

I found the expression in bottom to extract number of online peers from following command and its result is 0 instead of 5. It must be old expression I guess.

This is output from the command, /usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x "sip show peers" | grep "sip peers"

```
6 sip peers [Monitored: 5 online, 1 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 0 offline]

/usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x "sip show peers" | grep "sip peers" | sed 's/.* \([0-9]*\) online.*/\0/'
```

How to change the expression to extract number of online peers from Monitored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
/usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x "sip show peers" | sed '/^[0-9]\+ sip peers/s/.*Monitored: \([0-9]\+\) online.*/\1/
```

The sed command applies only on line starting with `sip peers` and will extract the number with the pattern `[0-9]\+` using the sed subtitution command `s` with `\1`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!